# Reading text in elements using lxml.etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I am using the Python version of the lxml libray. I am currently trying to parse the text from a table but am encountering a problem in that some of the text is links.

For example, one of the cells may look something like this:

```
<td>
    Can I kick it, <a>to all the people</a> who can quest like a <a>tribe</a> does
</td>
```

Say after parsing the html, the td element is stored as `foo`. Then `foo.text` will not display the whole text, only the parts that aren't links. Moreover, if I find the link text using `[i.text for i in foo.getchildren()]` I no longer know the order in which to put the non-link text and link text.

Is there an easy way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after searching for an hour, within 2 minutes of posting this question I have found the solution.

Use the method `foo.text_content()` and this will display what is needed.